# passing param thru command parameter

Tags: wpf, mvvm, light

how do i pass command param from `MenuItem`

```
<MenuItem CommandParameter="{Binding this, ElementName=Header}" />
```

OR how to pass a hardcoded string like

```
<MenuItem CommandParameter="something" />
```

I am using mvvm light, wpf

Comment: Your code looks fine to me .... can you provide a few more details?

Comment: If the hard-coded one works, but binding does not, check for binding errors in your debug output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try...

```
<MenuItem CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
               Path=Header}"/>
```

Comment: thanks man this works. Now lets say if i want to make it generic, instead of MenuItem I want to put up command on Menu, so that a particular MenuItem within it is clicked, command binds to same function but passed clicked MenuItem's Header

Comment: @NSingla Menu does not expose a Command or CommandParameter property out of the box